# Python - Cache function and decorator

Tags: python, caching, decorator

I am playing with cache functions using decorators.

First, I use a generic function

```
def memorize(func):
    cache = {}
    print "printing cache"
    print cache
    print "cache printed"    
    def decor_func(*args):
        if args in cache:
            print "cached value is found"
            return cache[args]
        else:
            print "calculating the value"
            val = func(*args)
            cache[args] = val
            return val
    return decor_func
```

Then I use it to decorate a function called `test`

```
def test(n):
    return n

test_decorated = memorize(test)
```

Then I get the following results

```
>>> test_decorated(1)
calculating the value
1
>>> test_decorated(2)
calculating the value
2
>>> test_decorated(1)
cached value is found
1
>>>
```

You can see that the second `test_decorated(1)` won't actually do any calculation, because we have already cache the result.

Now I want understand further, so I define

```
def test_cached(n):
    cache = {}
    print "printing cache"
    print cache
    print "cache printed"    
    if n in cache:
        print "cached value is found"
        return cache[n]
    else:
        print "calculating the value"
        val = n
        cache[n] = val
        return val
```

I thought that I will get the same results as above when I call `test_cached`.
However, the answer is NO, and the function `test_cached` didn't remember any calculated values. Here is the result:

```
>>> test_cached(1)
printing cache
{}
cache printed
calculating the value
1
>>> test_cached(2)
printing cache
{}
cache printed
calculating the value
2
>>> test_cached(1)
printing cache
{}
cache printed
calculating the value
1
>>>
```

As you can see, the second `test_cached(1)` re-calculate again the result.

I would like to know why these two approaches give different results, i.e.
why the first approach successfully caches the results, but the second fails

Answer (score 2):

`cache` is initialised when you do `cache = {}` which happens every time you call `test_cached`. Thus, the case is always empty (and useless) when you want to use it.

In your original code, `cache` is also initialised when you do `cache = {}` but you only do this when you call `memorize` which is done only once : when you do : `test_decorated = memorize(test)`.

When you call `test_decorated`, it kind of remembers which cache object is to be used (and modified if needed).

(If you want to learn more about this, it might be interesting to look up for closures in Python).